# Calculation units in EtherType frame field

Tags: ethernet, network-protocols

The EterType ethernet frame field value is represent a payload field length in bits or bytes?

Comment: Is this really something you couldn't figure out from a [five second google search and the resultant Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ethertype doesn't encode payload length, but the type of the payload packet in modern networks.

Originally, the field on that position could contain the payload length, naturally encoded in bytes, not bits (why on earth should you use bits as a unit here?).